# Stack python function debugging issue

Tags: python, debugging, stack

I have implemented the stack in python code.

```
class stack:
    arrlen = 0
    def __init__(self,arr,poin):
        self.arr = arr
        self.poin = poin
        arrlen = len(self.arr)

    def push(obj):
        self.poin = (self.poin+1)%arrlen
        self.arr[self.poin] = obj

    def pop():
        self.poin = (self.poin-1)%arrlen

    def printStack():
        for i in range(self.poin):
            print("",self.arr[i])
            print("\n")
```

I am try to run this code:

```
x = int(input("Hello.Please write down the number of tasks you want to do for today:\n"))
array = [None]*x
y = 0
mytasks = stack(array,x);
while(y is not 4):
    y = int(input("What do you want to do 1)add task 2) remove task 3)print remaining tasks 4)exit\n"))
    if y is 1:
            tsk = input("Write down the name of your task:\n")
            mytasks.push(tsk)
    if y is 2:
            mytasks.pop()
    if y is 3:
            mytasks.printStack()
```

However every time I type 1 to add a task to the stack when the push()function is called it stops debugging and it shows me a error message:

```
TypeError: stack.push() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What does this mean?

Before this issue I had had a issue with the **init** function so I had removed the arrlen variable but then I readded the arrlen variable so I dont know where I am wrong.I am using the IDLE Shell 3.10.4

Comment: Your instance methods all receive a `self` argument that you didn't include in your `def` statements.  Do `def push(self, obj)`, `def pop(self)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self is the first argument of every python class method. Therefore, your method push should look like something like:

```
def push(self, obj):

    self.poin = (self.poin+1)%arrlen

    self.arr[self.poin] = obj
```

And even the methods where you don't want to take any inputs, you should put self as the only parameter.